# C++ plugin Code editor live parsing error

Tags: qt, netbeans, java-native-interface, netbeans-7

I have a simple problem with the live parsing on NetBeans, which only affects the editor;

The code works correctly and all dependencies are been satisfied.
But the code editor seems not work correctly.

I've done several searches on the web, but I not found anything, just some old bugs of C++ plugin, but they all have been resolved.

**My setup is this (*QT library*):**

- OS: Mint 13 - 32x86
- NetBeans: 7.2
- Plugin C++: 1.18.1.1
- Qmake: 4.7
- Project type: Dynamic QT C++ Library
- Include JNI ref.: Yes;
- Include QT ref.: Yes;

[NetBeans with Error-> http://s1322.beta.photobucket.com/user/RTOSkit/media/Screenshot-10262012-021945PM.png.html](http://s1322.beta.photobucket.com/user/RTOSkit/media/Screenshot-10262012-021945PM.png.html)

*You can also see in the first image, which in the "navigator" missing prototype of the function*

**In this type of configuration(*C++ library with QT include*), the error disappears:**

- OS: Mint 13 - 32x86
- NetBeans: 7.2
- Plugin C++: 1.18.1.1
- GCC: 4.6
- Project type: C++ Dynamic Library
- Include JNI ref.: Yes;
- Include QT ref.: Yes;

It's just a graphic problem, the project works perfectly,
But in each line of code that I write, the code editor mark me a totally nonexistent error.

Is there any solution to this problem? Or am I just missing something in the configuration of the IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

Fortunately the problem was not caused by any bug in the C++ Plugin.

***But yes!* due to a inclusion priority in QT projects on NetBeansIDE.**

The JNI' includes should be made within the window

> "Options->C/C++->Code Assistance->C Compiler"

otherwise the include done in the

> "Options->C/C++->Code Assistance->C++ Compiler"

or in the

> "Properties->Build->QT->Expert->Custom Definitions-> "INCLUDEPATH
>   += "/..."

Will be evaluated only in the compilation step, allowing the compiler compile correctly; 
But the "code assistance" will not able to resolve the JNI' dependencies.

In the case of a C++ standard project (not QT), will suffice the JNI' includes in the

> "Options->C/C++->Code Assistance->C++ Compiler"

[image]